# Scrollbar disappears after form location/size changed

Tags: winforms

I have a form where I add controls programmatically, and the controls amount may reach an amount that will exceed the users screen resolution. At form_load I set the property `AutoScroll` to `true` and when I load the form, if it exceeds the screen resolution it shows the scroll bar and everything is fine until the user changes the properties of the form.
If the form is resized or moved, the scroll bar disappears.
I've tried using the form `LocationChanged` event and in the event, set `true` to`AutoScroll` but it failed.

Comment: When the user resizes the form and all the controls are now visble, the scrollbar will surely disappear

Comment: Say you have 100 controls, 20 in height for each. That's 2000 pixels height, which is over screen limits. I guess VS doesn't care if the form exceeds the screen bounds...

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I've set a size limitation on the form and it's no longer disappearing.